# How to make button effect out of circle

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML code link to back end python flask, I would like to create only one button that could make each HTML tr (table row) url_for works in a loop (line by line) to update DB record. but now the result is only the first line tr url_for works to update the record. the rest line didn't work at all.
Please help.

the code works for loop but has multiple button. each button in tr.

```
<tbody>
    {% for entry in entries %}
    <tr>
    <form action="{{url_for('log')}}" method="post">
      <td>{{entry.aa}}</td>
      <td>{{entry.bb}}</td>
      <td>{{entry.cc}}</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" type="submit" name="edit" value={{entry.id}}>Show Detail/Edit</button>
      </td>
    </form>
    </tr>
    {%endfor %}
</tbody>
```

I expect one button that run loop for all tr to trigger a url_for. that will update DB record. but no work for second tab row.

```
<form action="{{url_for('show')}}" method="post">
{% for entry in entries %}
       <tr>

           <td>
             <div class="form-group">
                 <input name="aa" value="{{entry.aa}}">
             </div>
           </td>
           <td>
             <div class="form-group">
                 <input name="bb" value="{{entry.bb}}">
             </div>
           </td>

       <td>
         <div class="form-group">
             <input name="cc" value="{{entry.cc}}">
        </div>
       </td>
  </tr>
     <!-- </form> -->
     {%endfor %}
   <div align="right">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Go</button>
 </div>
 </form>


@app.route("/show",methods=['POST','GET'])
def show():
     cur=g.db.execute('update box set aa=(\'%s\'),bb=(\'%s\') where cc=(\'%s\')'
            %(request.form['aa'],request.form['bb'],request.form['cc']))
     g.db.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making several forms when loop run.
you need to make only one form to submit all data at once. start form tag before loop starting and form tag end after loop end.
Make sure input fields name must be unique duplication will effect on all rows.

Comment: sorry, i think there's only one forms in my code. could be format problem that I paste it twice last time